# Why does this SQL code gives me the 2nd highest value in the salary column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found this SQL example on how to get the second highest value in salary column

```
SELECT AGENT_NAME, COMMISSION
  FROM [testDB].[dbo].[AGENTS] e
  WHERE 2 = (
    SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT COMMISSION)
    FROM [testDB].[dbo].[AGENTS] p
    WHERE e.COMMISSION<=p.COMMISSION)
```

I was trying to get the highest value in the salary column and I found the example above but I didn't quite understand the query. Can I have a full explanation line by line so I can understand the query?

Comment: The correlated subquery computes the number of distinct commissions not less then current one , `e.COMMISSION`. If this number is 2, the position of the current row regarding the commission is 2 exactly.

Comment: That is honestly an *odd* way of doing it. If you want the second highest value, `ROW_NUMBER` would make far more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to check how many "agents" have bigger commission then the current one. You can simple check this, removing the filtering and adding the expression in the select:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [AGENT_NAME] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[COMMISSION] MONEY
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([AGENT_NAME], [COMMISSION])
VALUES ('AGENT-1', 90)
      ,('AGENT-2', 70)
      ,('AGENT-3', 70)
      ,('AGENT-4', 40);

SELECT AGENT_NAME, COMMISSION,  (
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT COMMISSION)
FROM @DataSource p
WHERE e.COMMISSION<=p.COMMISSION) 
FROM @DataSource e;
```

[image]

Anyway, using [ranking functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) it's better in terms of readability and may be performance:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [COMMISSION] DESC) AS [Rank]
          ,[AGENT_NAME]
          ,[COMMISSION]
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE [Rank] = 2
```